# understanding a shell script code using expand function

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on shell script.

```
EXEC $CXCHOME+"/etc/expand_in_place" $MMSHOME+"/PDM/bin/pmr_pdm_aos"**

CXCHOME "/opt/ericsson/aos/PDM"
MMSHOME "/opt/ericsson/aos"
```

the code of expand_in_place is as below -

```
#!/bin/bash

. $INST_DATADIR/$PKG/install/aosbootcommon.sh

filename=`basename $1`

tmpfile="/tmp/$filename.$$"

rm -f "$tmpfile"
cp -p "$1" "$tmpfile"
echoLog "Expanding $1..."

expand "$tmpfile" "$1"
rm -f "$tmpfile"

cleanExit 0
```

I wanted to know the working of "expand_in_place".

Comment: What has this got to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Short answer: this shell script was coded by a spring water shrimp with boxing gloves (and probably with her feet). I hope this is not used on production machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Use /bin/bash program to process the code that follows.

```
. $INST_DATADIR/$PKG/install/aosbootcommon.sh
```

Read and execute the code in this file in the same process

```
filename=`basename $1`
```

Run the `basename` program, passing-in the first command-line argument (use `man basename` to find out what that does).  The back-ticks are a deprecated way to capture the output from a program.  In this case the output from `basename` is placed into the `filename` variable.

```
tmpfile="/tmp/$filename.$$"
```

Set the variable `tmpfile` to be /tmp, followed by the values of `filename`, followed by out current process id.  The `$` is an operator which gives us the value of a variable.  `$$` gives us the value of our current PID.

```
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Run the `rm` program passing these parameters : use `man rm` to find out what that does.

```
cp -p "$1" "$tmpfile"
```

Run the `cp` program passing those parameters: use `man cp` to find out what that does.

```
echoLog "Expanding $1..."
```

I have no idea what `echoLog` does, it is probably a local function defined in `$INST_DATADIR/$PKG/install/aosbootcommon.sh`

```
expand "$tmpfile" "$1"
```

Run the `expand` program using those parameters, use `man expand` to find out what that does.

```
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Run the `rm` program passing these parameters : use `man rm` to find out what that does.

```
cleanExit 0
```

I have no idea what `cleanExit` does, it is probably a local function defined in `$INST_DATADIR/$PKG/install/aosbootcommon.sh`